# What "rc" stands for in the latest Python 3.91rc1 version name

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

as mentioned in the title..

What "rc" stands for in the latest Python 3.91rc1 version name?

Thanks

Comment: Release candidate

Comment: Release Candidate?

Comment: [what-is-the-meaning-of-rc-in-semantic-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915541/what-is-the-meaning-of-rc-in-semantic-versioning) - 2nd hit on google for `version numner what stands rc for`

Comment: or choose one:  https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

Release Candidate

**Notes**

"In Software Versioning: A different approach is to use the major and minor numbers, along with an alphanumeric string denoting the release type, e.g. "alpha" (a), "beta" (b), or "release candidate" (rc)."

**Source**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Pre-release_versions